# Stopping my shirt from falling up when I run

Tags: comfort, travel

I like jogging to school - it's good exercise, and it makes me wake up in the morning.

I have to run with my (moderately heavy) school bag on, and my bag makes the back of my shirt ride up as I run. (When I take a step, my shirt and bag both bounce, and the bag catches my shirt before it can fall back down.) This makes me pull my shirt down about once a minute. It's very inconvenient.

How can I keep my shirt down so that I can happily run?

Comment: Gaffer's tape (won't leave stickiness)? Get used to the feeling of your shirt riding up and don't stop to adjust?

Answer (score 4):

How you are able to "happily run" beats me, but here are two thoughts which might help you on the way:

### Get bag closer to back

If you wear it like a [messenger bag](http://messengerbags.com/how-to-wear-a-messenger-bag/), close to your body it will move less. One way to get it really close is to put it over your shoulder, bend over forward, and tighten it real close to your chest.

Getting it close like described above, not only makes it move less, but it is actually making it easier and less stressful to carry.

### Lock shirt in place

Maybe not as easily done, as said. Two options spring to mind, and that is using longer shirts tucked well into trousers, and the other (maybe surer, but not as convenient) is to somehow strap it onto your trousers.
The latter could be done using clothespins (/pegs), safety pins, maybe a belt, or something similar.

Comment: I've tried tucking my shirt in without a whole lot of luck, but getting the bag closer seems like it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem as well. Here are a couple ideas:

1. Get a running shirt. These are designed to be very ultra-lightweight. Even if they do catch or run up a bit, it will just fall back down instead of catching on itself like a regular shirt. The downside is you have to wear a running shirt all the time.
2. Wear a tighter shirt so that it doesn't flop around when you run AND use a light rain jacket as a guard. The jacket should be also very lightweight and shiny so it acts as a barrier between your shirt and the backpack. It's less likely to snag when you run.

Answer (score 1):

When i run while wearing a backpack, the bag always ends up bouncing against my back, which is quite annoying. I discovered that some bags have a strap that you can strap around your waist, which prevents the bag from bouncing.

If you stop the bag from bouncing, it should stop your shirt from going up too.

Answer (score 1):

I attach the front of the hem of my T shirt to the buckle of my belt with a plastic karibiner. The T shirt then does not ride up, even when I am dancing. If the belt and the karibiner are the same colour no one will notice, it all just looks like part of the belt.